# Should I use "reader head", "playhead", or something else

Tags: word-choice, translation

I am developing a video processing software in which the user can browse though a video using a timeline interface.
I am wondering what to call the timeline "marker" which indicates the current video frame:

[image: example]

Is it playhead, read head, reader head, or something else?
In French, I would call this "tête de lecture".

Comment: In [VirtualDub](https://documentation.help/VirtualDub/documentation.pdf), it's called the 'position slider'. You could use 'marker' instead of 'slider'. Why would you borrow a term from VCR technology?

Comment: Because it seems to be what users of famous softwares (like Adobe Premiere Pro) name this marker (https://helpx.adobe.com/speedgrade/using/timeline-basics.html, couldn't find this for Premiere, but it is probably similar), but I have been told it is not right...

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey I dunno, why do we still say "dial" a phone, or call something a light "bulb" even when it isn't remotely bulb-shaped?  Why is a "save" icon still sometimes shaped like a floppy disk?  :-)

Comment: The term 'playback head' is a kind of metaphor employed by Adobe. Creators of other software don't use it. It feels a bit wrong because in tape machines, the tape moves and the 'playback head' stays in one place.

Comment: You could call it a ***cursor***

Comment: Don't use **cursor** unless the user can type there! You could use **playback head** or **playhead**. The latter is used by Camtasia (TechSmith) -- either one of those will be clear to your target audience.